# About Xcode developer beta2

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Upgrade my Xcode to db2 version, run my code and show this, how should I do [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1ZEJ.png)

Comment: This question will show when the iOS simulator is 9.x(9.1\9.2\9.3), not iOS10